# Importance of character array in tic- tac- toe

Tags: c++, c++11

I am beginer and making my first project on tic tac toe in c++

how flexible is using this

```
char ar[side][side]=''
for(int i=0;i<side;i++)
{ 
    if (ar[i][0] == ar[i][1] && ar[i][1] == ar[i][2] && ar[i][0] != ' ')
       return(true);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean with "flexible"?

Comment: You cannot grow or shrink this container at runtime. It will forget its own size if you pass it to a function. There is no iterator interface, so walking the elements will always involve indexing and bookkeeping. There is no easy way to create a view on this matrix (ie a sub-matrix or column). However, it is probably perfectly fine for what you intend to do with it.

Comment: @churill char ar[][]=' '; What is its significance and how can we use it at different places?

Comment: @DebidYadav Do you want to know, what a 2 dimensional array is???

Comment: @churill 2 dimensional character array is basically a string. But in this case I am using it to represent the boxes for tic- tac- toe game so I just want to know how to make the boxes look beautiful and interactive

Comment: @DebidYadav, yeah, no. A 2d-Character array might be an array of strings. But how to print the boxes nice, that's really another question than you asked here. Better open a new question.